# Detectar cuando un video concluye

Tags: javascript-objeto

Hago clic en un botón e inicia la reproducción de un video,al momento del clic el botón queda inhabilitado.
Requiero una función que detecte cuando finaliza el video y devuelva el foco a el botón donde se hizo clic.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#marcaVideo" onClick="carga03()"><img src="../jpg/taebaek.jpg">
```

**javascript**

```
 function carga03(e) { 
if (a!=e) {
    if (a!="") a.style.opacity=1;
   a=e;
e.style.opacity=0.4;

document.getElementById("subTVideo").innerHTML = 'POOMSAE TAEBAEK';
document.getElementById("mp4_src").src = "../videos/taebak.mp4";  
document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
} 
}
```

Comment: Lo que buscas es el evento [`ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event).

Answer (score 0):

El evento ended notifica cuando termina.
Ejemplo:

```
document.getElementById("myVideo").addEventListener("ended", function(){
//aca haces tu tarea.
});
```

No se si sea la sintaxis correcta.

```
var a=""
function carga01(e) {
if (a!=e) {
    if (a!="") a.style.opacity=1;
   a=e;
e.style.opacity=0.4;
```

document.getElementById("myVideo").addEventListener("ended", function(){
a.style.opacity=1;
a="";
document.getElementById("subTVideo").innerHTML = 'THE ITALIAN TOUR...';
document.getElementById("mp4_src").src = "../videos/intro.mp4";
document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
});

```
document.getElementById("subTVideo").innerHTML = 'POOMSAE KORYO';
document.getElementById("mp4_src").src = "../videos/koryo.mp4";
document.getElementById("myVideo").load();

}
}
```

Comment: Gracias checo y comento..